# Is there a way in Mule Dataweave 2 to transform the below

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I wanted to transform payload in xml to json format. I am running Mule 4 and Dataweave 2.
I tried using a flatten on teammangers but doest seem to have the desired result. My source is as below

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Report_Data>
  <Report_Entry>
    <Employee_ID>20081</Employee_ID>
    <Full_Name>Richard Axel</Full_Name>
    <Manager_Of_Team xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/CRINT005F_Team_Listing" wd:Descriptor="Dr. Richard Axel Lab (Richard Axel)">
      <ID wd:type="WID">d48b8f09725a105a7c6a31ac4ebf4c38</ID>
      <ID wd:type="Organization_Reference_ID">020453</ID>
    </Manager_Of_Team>
  </Report_Entry>
  <Report_Entry>
    <Employee_ID>20787</Employee_ID>
    <Full_Name>Edit Biro</Full_Name>
    <Manager_Of_Team xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/CRINT005F_Team_Listing" wd:Descriptor="Dr. Eero Simoncelli Lab (Edit Biro)">
      <ID wd:type="WID">d48b8f09725a105a7c6bb911d60a4e3c</ID>
      <ID wd:type="Organization_Reference_ID">057106</ID>
    </Manager_Of_Team>
    <Manager_Of_Team xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/CRINT005F_Team_Listing" wd:Descriptor="Dr. Ruth Lehmann Lab (Edit Biro)">
      <ID wd:type="WID">d48b8f09725a105a7c6bb69c22ff4e39</ID>
      <ID wd:type="Organization_Reference_ID">057105</ID>
    </Manager_Of_Team>
    <Manager_Of_Team xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/CRINT005F_Team_Listing" wd:Descriptor="SOO Rockefeller (Edit Biro)">
      <ID wd:type="WID">d48b8f09725a105a7c6a489ccb1c4c56</ID>
      <ID wd:type="Organization_Reference_ID">021001</ID>
    </Manager_Of_Team>
  </Report_Entry>
</Report_Data>
```

The expected output is as below

```
[
   {
      "empl_id": "20081",
      "teamManager": [
         "020453"
      ]
   },
   {
      "empl_id": "20787",
      "teamManager": [
         "057106",
         "057105",
         "021001"
      ]
   }
]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.Report_Data.*Report_Entry map {
    empl_id: $.Employee_ID,
    teamManager: $.*Manager_Of_Team..*ID filter ($.@"type"=="Organization_Reference_ID") 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Salim for the quick response that's exactly what I was looking for

Comment: This can be simplified a bit.  The map under teamManager is not needed, ie you can just use:
    teamManager: $.*Manager_Of_Team.*ID filter ($.@'type' == "Organization_Reference_ID")

Comment: Have updated the answer with the suggestion from @weissj . Not sure why i was doing that when i came up with the solution.